# Difference between screen.availHeight and window.height()

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, document

I am executing the following Javascript on my browser (Firefox).

1. console.debug("Screen height = "+ **screen.availHeight**); //outputs **770**
2. console.debug("Window Height ="+ **$(window).height()**);  //outputs **210** (I am using jQuery as well)

What is the difference between the two? Is 770 in pixels and 210 in mm?

Similarly, when I write `$(document).height()` and `$(window).height()`, there is a difference. What is the reason?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

## `window.outerHeight`

It's the height of the window on screen, it includes the page and all the visible browser's bars (location, status, bookmarks, window title, borders, …).

This **not** the same as jQuery's `$(window).outerHeight()`.

## `window.innerHeight` or `$(window).height()`

It's the height of the viewport that shows the website, just the content, no browser's bars.

## `document.body.clientHeight` or `$(document).height()`

It's the height of your document shown in the viewport. If it is higher than `$(window).height()` you get the scrollbars to scroll the document.

## `screen.availHeight`

It's the height the browser's window can have if it is maximized, including the browser's bars. So when the window is maximized, `screen.availHeight === window.outerHeight`

## `screen.height`

It simply matches the screen's resolution. So on a 1920×1080 screen, `screen.height` will be `1080`.

`screen.availHeight` is equal to [`screen.height` + the operating system's bars], like the taskbar on Windows, the dock and menu on OS X, or whatever is fixed on top or bottom of your screen if you're using Linux.

Comment: I agree with your answer but then what is $(window).height() and  why this value is different than screen.availHeight. I have already googled a lot over that but still no satisfactory answer. Further I see no documentation available which can tell the actual concept. By the way thanks for a super quick response. Thanks a lot again .

Comment: I've added an image to show the differences, I hope this will help.

Comment: @jigfox: its helps really. but how to calculate height when we re-sized window and then when we refresh window, `screen.height` only gives you inner height not including scroll height. how can we calculate scroll height? where as `screen.availHeight` gives you scroll height but it includes toolbar menu all this things.

Comment: it seems that Windows with Aero considers the full screen.height to be the same as screen.availHeight due to the transparency, how would I go about getting the screen.availHeight on a Windows Aero transparent taskbar system?

Comment: Love the graphical explanation! @Raje if you're using javascript, create a function that gets the window height. 

    function getWindowHeight() {
        $(window).height();
    }

Then call the function on $(window).load(); or $(window).resize();

Comment: $(window).height() is only accurate on webkit.  On IE and Firefox, horizontal scroll bars are not accounted for, so your results are off by the height of the scroll bar.

Comment: Note that `$(window).height()` will not work in combination with safari version and jquery version ( I dont know which exactly ). use `window.innerHeight` instead

Comment: in Windows 8 `screen.availHeight` is equal to `screen.height` **minus** the operating system's bars

Comment: screen.availHeight === window.outerHeight is not correct even when the window is maximized.

Comment: The situtation is a mess. IE 11 in Windows 10 yields (on a maximized window) `[screen.height, screen.availHeight, window.outerHeight, window.innerHeight]` = [864, 824, 838, 709] (it's funny that availHeight is smaller than outerHeight ...); Looking at Chrome (v56): it not even follows the spec (CSSOM View Module) as it gives you device pixels rather than CSS pixels. Chrome results for the above: [864, 864, 824, 759]. Zooming shows: only window.innerHeight is given in CSS pixels as it decreases with increasing zoom level.

Comment: @StevenPribilinskiy in macOS it also `screen.availHeight` is equal to `screen.height` **minus** the operating system's bars

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to **correct** a thing stated in @jigfox 's answer:

[https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_availheight.asp#:~:text=The%20availHeight%20property%20returns%20the,](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_availheight.asp#:%7E:text=The%20availHeight%20property%20returns%20the,))%2C%20use%20the%20availWidth%20property.

The **availHeight** property returns the height of the user's screen, in pixels, minus interface features like the Windows Taskbar.

Tip: To get the height of the screen (excluding the Windows Taskbar), use the availHeight property.