# Changing page scale via javascript

Tags: javascript, css, scale

I wish to scale the body of my website acording to resolution, but the code not seems to work:

```
document.body.style.transform: scale(window.screen.availHeight/2);
document.body.style['-o-transform'] = window.screen.availHeight/2;
document.body.style['-webkit-transform'] = window.screen.availHeight/2;
document.body.style['-moz-transform'] = window.screen.availHeight/2;
```

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044230/difference-between-screen-availheight-and-window-height).

Comment: What do you think `document.body.style.transform: scale(window.screen.availHeight/2);` does?

Comment: Magnifying the screen two times the resolution, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
document.body.style.transform = 'scale(' + window.screen.availHeight/2 + ')';
document.body.style['-o-transform'] = 'scale(' + window.screen.availHeight/2 + ')';
document.body.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'scale(' + window.screen.availHeight/2 + ')';
document.body.style['-moz-transform'] = 'scale(' + window.screen.availHeight/2 + ')';
```