# Need to sendkeys (CTRL + Add) to webdriver instance to zoom in/out of a webpage

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

public void resizeBrowser() {

```
    try {
        System.out.println("In resize unit");


        WebElement html = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));
        html.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.SUBTRACT));
        html.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.SUBTRACT));


        System.out.println("In resize unit3");

        html.click();
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It is getting marked duplicate again and again. please try to understand, what i am trying to do is a send keys operation on my FF56 webdriver instance to Zoom in and out. I dont need to set the zoom level of page by injecting JavaScript.

Comment: The issue is that none of the above stated ways are working, JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   js.executeScript("document.body.style.transform = 'scale(ZoomPercentage)';"); This too not working

Comment: When i am performing a manual key press "CTRL" + "ADD/SUB" , then the zoom In/Out is working fine on the webdriver instance, but not through script

Answer (score 0):

> The scale() CSS function defines a transformation that resizes an element on the 2D plane - [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)

Apparently, `document.body.style.zoom='80%'"` does not work in Firefox. You need to use the [scale(x)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) function. For example:

#### `document.body.style.transform = 'scale(1.2)'`

```js
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.body.style.transform = 'scale(1.2)'");
```

Some browser does not support it yet. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094301/changing-page-scale-via-javascript)

---

Generally it is better to use the [`scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scale) property instead of the `scale()` function. I recommend you to give it a try. It may work too.

#### Update:

I tested this code with selenium version `3.11.0` and geckodriver version `0.20.1`. It worked as expected.

Comment: How is your solution different from the dup marked discussion?

Comment: JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   js.executeScript("document.body.style.transform = 'scale(1.2)';"); - This too not working :-\

Comment: actually this zooms in/out that particular page. That too in a different way. The whole webpage comes in center if zoomed out. I want a code that does exactly what "CTRL"+"ADD/SUB" does on a FF web browser. so by that i mean, the code should permanently set a certain zoom level till the time that web driver instance is alive.