# iPad - Using a different js file, based on screen resolution

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a site for one of my friends...
And I am using media query for the css, to target monitors, iPad and other tablets...
For the interactivity, I'm using jquery 1.5...

The BIG QUESTION IS: 
- How can I make jQuery call multiple js files, depending on what resolution the viewer is using?

It would mean the World to me if somebody could help me out here...

Best Regards / Myung Ki

Comment: The question is: should you? Can't you just change the behaviour of your scripts, dependent on resolution or (more appropriately) browser window size?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use *one* set of js files, but handle the screen sizes early on in your program.  The most you'd want to do is to have different css files for each screen size; having one js file for each will turn out to be very difficult to manage.

You can use jQuery to get the window size and add the relevant classes to the `body` or `html` tag.  E.g., for large screens > 1024px across, you may add `extraWide` to `body`.  Then you can selectively format for wide screens with specific css like `body.extraWide`.

Also, in mobile devices, trap the `onorientationchange` event to reformat the layout based on the new orientation.  You may have classes called `portrait` and `landscape` added to `body` to have different css rules for different orientations.

Answer (score 0):

see [How to get screen resolution of visitor in javascript and/or php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091540/how-to-get-screen-resolution-of-visitor-in-javascript-and-or-php)