# Background image sizing/loading across different resolutions with Supersized

Tags: html, css

So I'm using Supersized to scale my background images and that's all good and well. The problem is that if I want the image to look good at multiple resolutions, it should be big, e.g. 2000 px * 2000 px. But why should someone with a resolution of e.g. 800 * 600 need to download such a large image? So what I'd like to do is to have, let's say, 3 sizes of the image (1024 * n, 1680 * n  and 2000 * n) and, depending on the resolution, the smallest possible of them would be sent to the user. Any thoughts on how I should implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Javascript's `window.screen.width` will return you the actual pixel width of the screen, so then you can use a simple if statement to select which image you will use.

```
if(window.screen.width < 1000) {
    image = "small.jpg";
} else {
    image = "large.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$(window).width();` (http://api.jquery.com/width/) to determine the user window width and then decide which image do you wish to use -

```
$('#yourImageId').attr('src', 'images/alt/imagename.jpg');
```

Comment: Doesn't this return the width of the browser rather than the screen? What if a 180P user maximises their browser after the check has been performed?

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091540/how-to-get-screen-resolution-of-visitor-in-javascript-and-or-php

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. The reason I suggest using the width of the screen rather than the window is because the user may have a high res screen but not have their browser maximised.  In that case you would deliver a low-res image, which would look nasty if the user then decides to maximise their screen. `window.screen.width` returns the actual monitor resolution: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Many ways:

1. As others said, get the width of the screen, then based on that, manipulate the background image source of the element.
2. Use [**Less**](http://www.lesscss.org) to create programmatic CSS at client-side
3. Use the concept of [**responsive-images**](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/responsive-images/)